# Issue with qml files and designer tab of QtCreator of Qt5.4mingwRC1

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I’ve recently installed Qt5.4mingwRC1 on windows and it works without any problem but there is an issue with QML files and the designer. I’ve got some problems with the design tab inside Qtcreator.

On all qml file (even with example projects), i have an error message “Using Qt Quick code model instead of Qt Quick2 (M324) (4:1)” and i can’t use the design editor.

How to Solve this? Before Qt5.4 I was using Qt5.3 and there was no such that error.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the `QML_IMPORT_PATH` to the proper installation. See upstream bug reports about this kind of issues:

[Designer uses default kit instead of current active](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-12356)

[QmlParser takes only kits in account known at startup](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11040)

Comment: I write this code in the project file but it didn't solve my problem: QML_IMPORT_PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\qml

Comment: @Mosi: for QtQuick2, you need `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`. Also, check `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` for more information.

Comment: adding these didn't help me :( QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1
QML2_IMPORT_PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\qml

Comment: Please check if import paths work from console. Also, `QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1` is a _debugging_ directive. Please paste the output of it.